# Как правильно отрисовать компонент поверх других компонентов с помощью React-Router-Dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Первый раз использую react-router-dom, и появилась проблема.. компонент Menu отображаеться снизу над другими компонентами, мне нужно чтобы при нажатии выводился только компонент Menu.

```js
import React from 'react'
import Association from './Pages/Association'
import "./Index.scss"
import Menu from './UI/Menu';
import { Route, BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'


function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="app">
        <Association />
        <div className="app-wrapper" >
          <Route path="/menu" component={Menu} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>

  );
}

export default App;
```

Смотрел несколько видео и прочитал несколько статей но ничего полезного не нашел.

Comment: Тогда надо скрыть на верхнем уровне компонент `Association`. И добавить `Link`

Comment: А как правильно это сделать?

Comment: Так я же написал наверху. У вас код не воспроизводимый поэтому мне остаётся только ванговать.

Comment: Извени, не увидел что вы посоветовали. Я не понял  к чему именно добавить Линк?

Comment: Link присвоить компоненту Menu?

Comment: Link это компонент из react-router-dom по клику перенаправляет в соответственный роут https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link .Вам нужно убрать Association и добавить какой-нибудь навигационный панель с компонентами Link и получить что-то наподобие header-а.Но я рекомендую вам с начало прочитать документацию react-router-dom